# How to Calculate an Import to Receive considering Fees.

Tags: finance, percentages

I have a problem: I want to receive a sum but, to receive that sum, I have to pay a percentual fee on this transaction.

For example: if I want to receive 20 and fee is 10%, I can't require 20 + 10% (so 22) because I would receive 19,80 (22 - 10%).

So, what is the correct formula to calculate the sum I have to require to receive an import?

Comment: Let the value of the (net-)import be $x$ and $p$ the prozentual fee rate. Then you have to calculate $(1+p)\cdot x $ to get the required payment. Note that $0.1$ is equal to $10\%$

Comment: What's "(net-)import"? Can you make an example using my example datas (20$ and 10%)?

Comment: Net import in this case means the value of the import (without fees) is $\$20$. Then you have to pay $10\%$ of the value for fee. That means it total you have to pay $\$20\cdot (1+0.1)=\$20\cdot (1.1)=\$22$. I hope this is was the Intention of your qestion. If not, make a clarification.

Comment: No that's wrong because if I ask you to send me 22 and I pay 10% of fees I will receive 19,80 instead of 20. I've already explained this in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have a net value of $\$20$. And $10\%$ of the total payment is the fee. Therefore $90\%$ is equivalent to $\$20$. Now you calculate the equivalent to $100\%$

Thus the total amount, which has to be payed is  $20\cdot \frac{100\%}{90\%}=22\frac{2}{9}\approx 22.22$

And the fee is $\$22.22-\$20=\$2.22$

Comment: Wow that's right, thank you very much!